# Is it possible to remotely update an Android application running in Kiosk mode?

Tags: android, mdm, kiosk-mode

I have tried several MDM like flyve mdm and cloud4mobile but none of them offers the posibility to remotely update an app running in kiosk mode

Comment: Remotely update an application via Play store? or without play store?

Comment: With or without. Is it possible to automatically and remotely update an app using Play Store that is running in Kiosk mode?

Comment: Yes it is possible via play store if you can push the policy. 
Does Flyve or Cloud4Mobile allow you to change the policies of the application in the PolicyBody?